# Has anyone had problems fitting the stalactites and stalagmites in the 76252 Lego Batcave?

Tags: building, instructions

I have got to stage 403 and, whilst I have had problems fitting the pieces together previously, at this stage I simply cannot get the stalactites or stalagmites to fit into the studs - they seem to have a bulbous end and they simply will not fit. Is glue the answer? Has anyone else had the problem?

Comment: I guess you have a question regarding 76252 set? Glue is NEVER an answer for official LEGO set. It would also help if you added a picture of your assembly at a location you are having issue with.

Answer (score 2):

Step 403 of the [instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/76252) for set [76252 - Batcave - Shadow Box](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76252-1) constructs two stalactites like follows, so I'll assume that's the set you're talking about :

[image]

Given your description of what doesn't work for you, the only thing I can think of is that you're trying to insert the [1x1 round stud with hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85861) (the middle part in the assembly) upside down. Look closely at the image, and make sure it's the right side up, and it should fit just fine.

Comment: No I am definitely trying to insert it at the right end !

Comment: @MikeP : then it should fit as shown. Can you clarify what you mean by "a bulbous end" ? Maybe add a photo to your question ?